# Why am I getting "Error: datatable does not exist in current context" in this try-catch block?

Tags: c#, asp.net, try-catch

Here is my code which works:

```
DataTable myDataTable = new DataTable();
try
{
    // Code Logic
}
catch (Exception exp)
{
    //Handle Exception
}
finally
{
    myDataTable.Dispose();
}
```

It looks fine and shows no compile error

But when I declare the datatable inside the try potion it shows an error:

> The name 'myDataTable' does not exist in the current context

Here is the code attempting this:

```
try
{
    DataTable myDataTable = new DataTable();
}
catch (Exception exp)
{
    //Handle Exception
}
finally
{
    myDataTable.Dispose();
}
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Scoping. It's declared within the `try` block, so it only exists there.

Comment: so how to dispose such elements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you declare a DataTable within a block, it is local to that block. You need to declare it outside the block to access it outside the block.

Alternatively, you can use `using` which will dispose DataTable after that block is executed:

```
using(DataTable myDataTable = new DataTable())
{
   try
   { ... }
   catch (Exception exp)
   {
       //Handle Exception
   } 
} 
//data table is disposed after this
```

Answer (score 1):

In the second case you limit the scope of `myDataTable` variable with the just `try` block part.

You can fix it like this:

```
    DataTable myDataTable;
    try
    {
        myDataTable = new DataTable();
    }
    catch (Exception exp)
    {
        //Handle Exception
    }
    finally
    {
        myDataTable.Dispose();
    }
```

Comment: In general, finally block can throw you NullReferenceException, when the constructor of DataTable will throw any exception. In costruct like this, you should check myDataTable for null in finally block.

Comment: @DavidGregor in general you are right, but this specific question was "Why is it so???", which implies basic talks about variable scope rather than all that usingdisposablefinalizersnulls...

Comment: I totally agree. Anyway when you post here piece of code which is free to use, I would expect not to have any possible "bugs" which are visible at first glance

Answer (score 0):

When inside the `try` block, it will be declared within that 'inner' scope. If you want to manipulate it, or do anything with it, it'll have to be outside the `try`.

In a similar way if you declare variables inside an `if` clause. It's within the scope of that block.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you're using it in different scope. Your `DataTable` is *inside* `try` block, thus making it inaccessible *inside* `finally` block.